# android http class cast exception

Tags: android, http

I am getting a ClassCastException:java.lang.string from the following code

```
try {
        se = new StringEntity(myJson);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    httppost.setEntity(se);
    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

I am using the apache libray.   Is there a cast that I can't see, any help on the cause appreciated.   Might it be the setEntity(se) call?

Comment: Please post the stack trace; we don't have ESP :)

Answer (score 3):

It would be really helpful if you could post the whole stack trace - we're kind of guessing otherwise.

That said, the line I'd take a look at is:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

It looks like the return type of `httpClient.execute(HttpUriRequest, ResponseHandler)` depends on the type of ResponseHandler you pass in. Since you're passing in an instance of `BasicResponseHandler`, which returns the response body as a String, I'm guessing that method invocation is going to return an instance of `java.lang.String`.

You can try changing that line to something like:

```
String responseBody = httpClient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

But, that's just a guess, given that we don't have a full stack trace.

Comment: An answer appeared on here briefly which suggested the problem was in the line

Comment: ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); and that proved to be correct.   For some reason that answer was withdrawn before I could tick it!   Why does this comment box fire off prematurely if I hit the return key?

Comment: Seems to be correct. I had the same problem, just removed the responseHandler and it returned a HttpResponse object